# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, csproj, visual-studio-2019

When I trying to develop a WebApp using .Net core. This error kept on coming 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

I added the proper version number.
I attached my Csproj file down
Not able to reolve this. Help me

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" version="2.2.0  " />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Admin\Controllers\Views\Category\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing out the line from

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.2" />
```

To this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Comment: It makes more error in the solution. All my data models shows error